# passing args to fns of n parameters in a syntactically consistent way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Scalaz has a thrush operator `|>` defined something like this:

```
implicit class ThrushOps[A](self: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A ⇒ B): B = f(self)
}
```

I have a few functions of various arguments:

```
def f1(x:Int)=x+1
def f2(a:Int, b:Int)=(a+1,b+1)
def f3(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int)=(a+1,b+1,c+1)
```

The way I can call them is syntactically different dependending if they have 1 or more args:

```
4 |> f1
(1,2) |> (f2 _).tupled
(1,2,3) |> (f3 _).tupled
```

What is a way to make calling a function with one argument consistent to calling a function with n arguments from a syntactic point of view?

I want to be able to write

```
4 |> f1
(1,2) |> f2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with two ways, but both only let you write consistent

```
4 |> f1 _
(1,2) |> f2 _
```

and still require doing something for each arity.

Option 1:

```
class MyFn[A, B](f: A => B) {
  def apply(x: A): B = f(x)
}
object MyFn {
  implicit def from1[A, B](f: A => B): MyFn[A, B] = new MyFn(f)
  implicit def from2[A1, A2, B](f: (A1, A2) => B): MyFn[(A1, A2), B] = new MyFn(f.tupled)
  implicit def from3[A1, A2, A3, B](f: (A1, A2, A3) => B): MyFn[(A1, A2, A3), B] = new MyFn(f.tupled)
}

implicit class ThrushOps[A](self: A) {
  def |>[B](f: MyFn[A, B]): B = f(self)
}
```

Option 2:

```
implicit class ThrushOps[A](self: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A ⇒ B): B = f(self)
  def |>[C1, C2, B](f: (C1, C2) ⇒ B)(implicit ev: A =:= (C1, C2)): B = f.tupled(self)
  def |>[C1, C2, C3, B](f: (C1, C2, C3) ⇒ B)(implicit ev: A =:= (C1, C2, C3)): B = f.tupled(self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apply:

```
implicit class ThrushOps[A](self: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A ⇒ B): B = if (self.isInstanceOf[Product]) f.apply(self) else f(self)
}
```

You can also use manifest to enforce more accurate check

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense: 1. As I understand, the question is how to change signature of `|>` to make the code at the end compile, and you don't change the signature at all. 2. `f(self)` is the same as `f.apply(self)`, so you don't meaningfully change the body either.